# Actions on options of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

i cant get both values on selecting dropdown options. Only one output gives not both. Please help to solve this. i want to show value in output field when i select fahrenheiet it should give in celsius and vice versa.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

   function findCelsius()
   {
    var vals = document.getElementById("convert").value;
    if(vals = "F"){
     var v = document.getElementById("vlues").value;
     var celsius = (v - 32) * 5/9;
     
     var result = Math.ceil(celsius);
     
     document.getElementById("answer").value = result;
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You Selected: Farenheit to Celsius!";
    }
    else if(vals = "C")
    {
     var va = document.getElementById("vlues").value;
     var fah = (va * 9/5) + 32;
     
     var result = Math.ceil(fah);
     
     document.getElementById("answer").value = result;
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You Selected: Celsius to Fahrenheit!";
    }
  
  }
  
  
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Conversion</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Convert Temprature</h2>
<form name="conversion">
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             Enter a Value
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="number" name="vlue" value="" id="vlues">
             <select id="convert" onChange="findCelsius()">
                 <option value="F">Farenheight(F°)</option>
                    <option value="C">Celsius(C°)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="text" id="answer" name="result" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
             Answer:
            </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
            </td>
            <td>
             <span id="output"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Condition declaration was wrong use `==` instead `=`

```js
function findCelsius() {
  var vals = document.getElementById("convert").value;
  if (vals == "F") {
    var v = document.getElementById("vlues").value;
    var celsius = (v - 32) * 5 / 9;

    var result = Math.ceil(celsius);

    document.getElementById("answer").value = result;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You Selected: Farenheit to Celsius!";
  } else if (vals == "C") {
    var va = document.getElementById("vlues").value;
    var fah = (va * 9 / 5) + 32;

    var result = Math.ceil(fah);

    document.getElementById("answer").value = result;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You Selected: Celsius to Fahrenheit!";
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Conversion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Convert Temprature</h2>
  <form name="conversion">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Enter a Value
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="vlue" value="" id="vlues">
          <select id="convert" onChange="findCelsius()">
                 <option value="">select</option>
                 <option value="F">Farenheight(F°)</option>
                    <option value="C">Celsius(C°)</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="answer" name="result" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Answer:
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="output"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome @ShaheenAsghar .My answer is usefull [mark it as a answer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZpJaq8YrVAhXIKo8KHUIOBJsQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fsomeone-answers&usg=AFQjCNHZ4IpbyGACPNwGrF1LYJUvBvZJGw).its helpfull for the future visitor's